# How does Tokio's Handle::block_on differ from Runtime::block_on?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

How does `tokio::runtime::Handle.block_on` differ to `tokio::runtime::Runtime.block_on`? The `Handle.block_on` causes some code to hang whereas the `Runtime.block_on` works fine.

This is how I create the `Handle`. The `Runtime` is the same minus the last 2 lines.

```rust
let runtime = runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
    .enable_all()
    .build()
    .unwrap()
    .handle() // not needed for Runtime
    .clone(); // ---
```

Then I call a function which with this:

```rust
async fn run(){
    // calls get data
}

self.runtime.block_on(run())
```

This is the code where it hangs. When running from the `Runtime` it works fine, with the `Handle` it hangs at `TcpStream::connect()`.

```rust
async fn get_data(addr: String) -> Result<Data> {
    let c = TcpStream::connect(addr.clone()).await?; // hangs here
    let t = get_data_from_connect(c).await?;
    return Ok(t);
}
```

Comment: Difference is explained clearly in [official doc](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.10.1/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.block_on). Your problem occurs because you are losing `runtime` with that functional pipe, and this leads runtime to shutdown, please try [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08aa57ea38f15c4ac3ba31a8de5c3ff9) and see the difference.

Comment: @ÖmerErden what is "that functional pipe"?

Comment: @c-f the chain of method calls. When you `clone` the handle, Rust sees no relation between the cloned handle and the runtime,so the runtime is dropped, therefore you have a handle to a runtime that's been shut down. That's what happens without the clone, except without the compile error, because by `clone`-ing the handle you've worked around the compile error rather than fixed it.

Comment: @Masklinn I have fixed the issue and posted what my solution was. I am not sure what to change the title of the question to but it doesn't make sense because I was looking in the wrong direction for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by making sure that the `Runtime` object does not go out of scope and get dropped. I was under the impression that only the `Handle` is needed to keep the runtime alive but [only the `Runtime` object itself can](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.10.1/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#shutdown).